# Mysql procedure, If statement

Tags: mysql

How do i make an if statment that ROLLBACK: if the studentbrukernavn (students username) already exist, and if the klassekode (classcode) does not exist

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS OPPRETT_STUDENT$$
CREATE PROCEDURE OPPRETT_STUDENT
(
    IN bilde_bildenr INT,
    IN bilde_filnavn VARCHAR(30),
    IN bilde_beskrivelse VARCHAR(30),
    IN student_brukernavn VARCHAR(30),
    IN student_fornavn VARCHAR(30),
    IN student_etternavn VARCHAR(30),
    IN student_klassekode VARCHAR(30)
)
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO bilde
    VALUES (bilde_bildenr,
            CONCAT('bilder/',student_brukernavn,'.jpg'),
            CONCAT('bilde av ',student_fornavn,' ',student_etternavn)
            );
    INSERT INTO student VALUES (student_brukernavn, student_fornavn, student_etternavn, student_klassekode, bilde_bildenr);
COMMIT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF  NOT EXISTS(SELECT query) THEN
ELSE
 END IF;

Hope this helps
```

Comment: i need it to do a rollback

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.